# Is there an error display app?

Tags: applications

Is there an app for android that displays an error when an app or game crashes ? Because in windows, when a program crashes , an error is always displayed revealing a reason for crash. Eg. It says ' * file is missing','incompatible graphics card' etc. But  an android app quits, or fails to install without explanation. So is there an app that displays errors that explain, for example if an app needs a specific android version, what gpu works with it, or it is not an original  etc.

Comment: There is always a crash report I guess

Answer (score 0):

There is no general, automatic way to find out a human-understandable reason why an app failed to install/run/work.  It is definitely *not* true that Windows apps always fail with a sensible error message.

> if an app needs a specific android version

Apps contain [explicit information](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) about what versions of Android they target and support.  This information is displayed in the Play Store and other app stores, or you can find it using one of the tools listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4191762/507761).

> what gpu works with it

Ideally this would be published by the developer/app store as well.

> it is not an original

Don't pirate apps.

---

To get other errors/logging or stack traces, you can use the `logcat` command from ADB or a local shell on your device.  There are also apps like [aLogcat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat) to provide a graphical interface.

Answer (score 0):

Your best opportunity to do this is using:

```
adb shell logcat
```

with your device hooked up to a computer in debug mode. It will provide a live stream of debug info, from which you can ascertain the cause of any failure. It's not as easy as what you want but it does the job you need.